# Как добавить свои данные в таблицу очереди jobs Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет
У меня есть таблица jobs куда я добавил новую колонку myColumn. Как заполнить данными колонку myColumn, при использовании Mail:later, или в handle Jobs класса

Answer (score 1):

Например можно так:

```
\DB::table('jobs')->insert(['myColumn'=>'значение']);
```

или можно создать модель и работать в данными через нее

Comment: Нет как именно через менеджер очереди добавлять, при добавлении(создании) очереди

Comment: как вариант, можно создать событие и вызывать его при создании/добавлении очереди